# Pandas: How to apply a groupby with as_index=False

Tags: pandas, group-by

I need to translate this sql query in python:

```
SELECT VAR1, COUNT (VAR1) AS LINES, MAX(VAR2) 
FROM DF
GROUP BY VAR1
```

And I need to do obtain the var1 as column (as_index=False). The problem is I am not able to rename the COUNT(*) function. So the only thing I can do is this:

```
DF=DF.groupby('VAR1',as_index=False).agg({'VAR1':np.size,'VAR"':np.max})
```

but obviously I obtain this error:

```
ValueError: cannot insert VAR1, already exists
```

does anybody know a way to rename the VAR1 within the GROUPBY?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for change `index` name and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) works perfectly:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'VAR1':[1,1,3],
                   'VAR':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],})

print (DF)
   C  VAR  VAR1
0  7    4     1
1  8    5     1
2  9    6     3

DF=DF.groupby('VAR1')
     .agg({'VAR1':np.size,'VAR':np.max})
     .rename_axis('New')
     .reset_index()
print (DF)
   New  VAR1  VAR
0    1     2    5
1    3     1    6
```